# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent Join table with multiple condition join having count

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent, having-clause

I have question about left join table which using having count to select main table to be shown with the condition described as below:

```
select  b.id, b.location_name, b.box_identity
from    box b
    left join device d on b.id = d.box_id
                      and d.deleted_at is null
group by b.id, b.location_name, b.box_identity
having count(d.*) < COALESCE(b.device_slot, 3)
order by b.id desc
```

i have tried using eloquent code like this, but DB::raw is not working in $join function

```
$boxes = Box::leftJoin('device', function($join) {
    $join->on('box.id', '=', 'device.box_id');
    $join->on(DB::raw('device.deleted_at is null'));
})
->select('box.id', 'box.box_identity', 'box.location_name')
->groupBy('box.id', 'box.box_identity', 'box.location_name')
->havingRaw('COUNT(device.*) < COALESCE(box.device_slot, 3)')
->orderBy('box.id', 'desc')
->get();
```

How can i achieve this query using laravel eloquent? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can try `$join->whereRaw('device.deleted_at is null');`

Comment: @haidang yeah, i think your answer is the right one. thanks a lot, haidang!

Comment: Not at all, my friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this :

```
$boxes = Box::leftJoin('device', function($join) {
    $join->on('box.id', '=', 'device.box_id');
    $join->whereRaw('device.deleted_at is null');
})
```

Comment: i think it's should using $join->on('device.deleted_at','=',DB::raw('NULL'));

but still, the result is not valid. box which has 3 devices installed is still shown, it must be not shown.

Comment: try DB::enableQueryLog();
dd(DB::getQueryLog()); at the end. then post the query here

Comment: Your query will check `deleted_at  = "NULL"` string instead of `deleted_at is null` in MySQL. In this case, must use `raw query`.

Comment: @BRjava yup, now this is the right one, like haidang's answer